# WebStorm (temporary) ESLint-error "no-trailing-spaces" when adding newline between two methods

Tags: typescript, eslint, webstorm

I am using TypeScript (Angular) in the WebStorm IDE by JetBrains.

When coding, obviously you would want a newline between method-definitions, to separate them visually.

Every time I put a newline between two method-definitions squiggly lines and the error "no-trailing-spaces" appears.

This is how the code-interface in the IDE looks before inserting the newline:

[image: image before]

After putting a newline character (that is, hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key) with the cursor at the end of line 71, this happens:

[image: image after]

**EDIT:**

Actually, while writing this, I realized the error goes away a few seconds after you move the cursor and <kbd>Alt + Tab</kbd> out and back into WebStorm, so it's probably the fault of WebStorm and not ESLint.

Still decided to post this. Maybe someone knows how to make this "cursor-movement + alt-tab" not necessary as it is **still irritating/distracting** having red squiggly lines show up after you don't do anything wrong.

Comment: By default, when you do "Alt + Tab out", the IDE saves the file. When it saves, it takes your settings into an account, in this case it's about trailing spaces. ESLint integration runs on the editor buffer (the raw content gets saved into a temp file **as is**), hence the error (because the trailing space is there in the editor. But when you get back, the error is gone, because the file got "properly" saved (and trailing whitespace was removed).

Comment: That's most likely what is going on. To check that: 1) make sure to enable displaying the whitespace characters -- so you can clearly see if it's there when the error is shown or not. I believe it will be there. 2) Enable "Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Editor Tabs | Mark modified (*)" option -- it will draw the asterisk on the editor tab (file icon) if file is not yet saved. The check if it will disappear after you came back from "alt+tab out". If it does .. well, just hit the Save to save the modified files and it should work the same.

Comment: Exactly what you described happened.

This post also mentions it:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003335499/comments/360002366779

I guess there is no fix for this (besides manually saving every time after separating function defintions etc. by enter) but it's good to know that it's not me doing something wrong but instead the IDE and ESLint not cooperating. 

Just curious why noone else seems to be bothered by this, as this is the first Stackoverflow post on this. Maybe few people use the combination of WebStorm+ESLint...

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003335499-Enter-creates-indented-new-line?page=1#community_comment_360002366779

Disabling smart indent as described here did not change anything for me, even after restarting.

Comment: Yes, Smart Indent on Enter is what creates that indent. With that option disabled it should put the caret at the start of the new line (with no indent) when you press Enter. Maybe it works differently in some contexts. I'm not JavaScript person and do not have any "proper" files to try this there. if you can provide me with some dummy file (that has enough content to do the test) I can play around here, maybe will spot something...